# assistance with dropzone js / php basics

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am trying to setup a simple dropzone js image upload thing on a wordpress page and having a lot of trouble.  Reading all kinds of stuff but there are some things I am really unsure on.

I have the dropzone js/and css files as I should...

and i have the form as the instructions say:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/kal_plugin_pituka/dropzone.css">
<script src="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>/wp-content/plugins/kal_plugin_pituka/dropzone.js"></script>


<form action="/wp-content/plugins/kal_plugin_pituka/save_image.php"
    class="dropzone"
    id="my-awesome-dropzone">

    </form>
```

I have the right path for the destination file for the form...

here is that "save_image.php" file:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error)  {
if ( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {                
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key];

    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
    $file_extension = end((explode(".", $name))); # extra () to prevent notice

    $targetPath = "/pathway/";  //4

    $file_new_name = uniqid(). '.'. $file_extension;

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $file_new_name  ;  //5

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6    
  }
} 

}

else {
echo "files array is empty";
echo "<br/>";
}

echo $targetFile;
```

Now here is what I am really unclear on.  The instructions for all of this do not include a "submit" button on the form.

When I added a submit button to that form; it basically goes to my destination file and tells me the $__files is empty...

so I am not sure what all is going on here; pretty sure the file is not too big as just a 500px image...

but I am really unclear on how this is all triggered without the submit button.

If you just read the directions - then there is no mention of a submit button.  So I am wondering what it is that triggers the "code" in the destination file to run.  Will it run when the image is dropped in the box without any button being pressed?

Or if there is a submit button needed - anything special i need to know about it to make it work with this?

BTW - the submit button i tried was:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I just put that right before the closing form tag.

If i do not have a submit button; then basically upon dropping an image; nothing happens after that...

If anyone can help with this I would really appreciate it.

All the best,  G

Comment: dropzone will send the file as soon as you drop it. Also there is a PHP tutorial on their site http://www.dropzonejs.com/.